# Unable to verify fpm seeing pm.* configuration settings

Tags: php-fpm

I'm trying to enable dynamic process management for php-fpm v7.3.  Here's my **php-pm.ini**

```
[www]
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 498
```

The problem is that I can't seem to confirm my fpm is seeing the changes.  I can see that it's parsing the ini file:

```
$ docker-compose exec web php -i | grep "pm."

Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-pm.ini
```

Looking at the `phpinfo()` service by fpm I don't see any of the `pm.` settings at all.  How can I verify these settings are being picked up?  And if they are but wouldn't show here, how can I *prove* it?

Comment: It is not possible as far as i know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not see these settings with `php -i`, because it's rather code related settings. Try setting `pm.status_path = /status` and then go to your http://localhost/status URL and there you will see your php-fpm options.

also you can look at process list to see which config file is currently used with command `ps aux | grep php-fpm | grep master` or you will see it in output of command `php-fpm -t`.

Of course you have to pass it to your docker container.

**Edit by OP/Webnet**

This solution led me part of the way, but there were other pieces that helped me solve it.  Since this took me down the initial path I want to make sure patok gets credit so I'll expand on the solution here.

Rather than loading an additional ini file via `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/`, what I needed to do was modify fpm's configuration at `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` inside my container (you could add an additional `.conf` file if you want, but I didn't).  Adding this to the dockerfile did the task:

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/pm = .+?/pm = dynamic/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_children = \d/pm\.max_children = 35/' \
 -e 's/pm\.start_servers = \d/pm\.start_servers = 10/' \
 -e 's/pm\.min_spare_servers = \d/pm\.min_spare_servers = 5/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_spare_servers = \d/pm\.max_spare_servers = 20/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_requests = \d/pm\.max_requests = 500/' \
 -e 's/pm\.process_idle_timeout = .+?/pm\.process_idle_timeout = 10s/' \
 /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

I was able to confirm this solution worked by following the practices outlined in [PHP-FPM: Process Management](https://serversforhackers.com/c/php-fpm-process-management) which included using `ab -n 10000 -c 200 http://localhost/index.php` to simulate 10k requests to my site, enabling me to use `docker-compose exec web ps aux | grep php-fpm` (as mentioned by patok) to see that the number of fpm processes had indeed been increased to handle the load.

Comment: Setting `pm.status_path` seems to not be making it past my Laravel app to fpm.  I'm seeing my application's 404 page.  My nginx config forwards requests to `localhost:9000` so I _should_ be able to execute `docker-compose exec web curl localhost:9000/status` and see the page.  But that returns a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.  FYI `web` has both fpm and nginx running on it.

Comment: `php-fpm` shows the file `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf` in use, but I have configured fpm to load multiple files.  `php -i | grep ini` in the container shows that `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-pm.ini` is being parsed, which is where the config is.

Comment: `docker-compose exec web ps aux | grep php-fpm` only shows 3 total processes, 1 master and 2 children which isn't what's in my config which I suppose means it's not being read as expected.

Comment: Main php-fpm.conf (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf in your case) is usually being used for some global configuration and also for inclusion of files in conf.d (/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/), so check your main config file for `include` directive (it should be set to something like `include=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/*.ini`). Then you could say, that your php-pm.ini inside conf.d directory is being properly loaded. Although I'm not sure about file extentions used - php-fpm, at least from what I can see on our Ubuntu and CentOS servers, use .conf not .ini extension. So be aware of this as well.

Comment: Got it working!  Thanks for the help - I submitted edits to your original answer to cover what I ended up doing to make it work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: "\d" was was not working on my container build. replaced it with [0-9]\+ `RUN sed -i -e 's/pm = .+?/pm = dynamic/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_children = [0-9]\+/pm\.max_children = 35/' \
 -e 's/pm\.start_servers = [0-9]\+/pm\.start_servers = 10/' \
 -e 's/pm\.min_spare_servers = [0-9]\+/pm\.min_spare_servers = 5/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_spare_servers = [0-9]\+/pm\.max_spare_servers = 20/' \
 -e 's/pm\.max_requests = [0-9]\+/pm\.max_requests = 500/' \
 -e 's/pm\.process_idle_timeout = .+?/pm\.process_idle_timeout = 10s/' \
 /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`